# How to change arrow and text on click?

Tags: jquery

So i have this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L03e5hty/)  I want when user click on Advanced it will expand menu and it will change text "ADVANCED" to "BASIC" and it will change arrow from down to UP. Any suggestion?

```
function toggleChevron(e) {
    $(e.target)
   .prev('.panel-heading')
   .find("i")
   .toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down')
}

$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like following.

```
function toggleChevron(e) {
    var link = $(this);
    if (link.text().trim() == 'ADVANCED')
        link.html('BASIC <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-up"></i>')
    else
        link.html('ADVANCED <i class="indicator fa fa-angle-down"></i>')
}

$('#headingOne a').on('click', toggleChevron);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/L03e5hty/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to bind click event on your accordion instead of the ones you did. Then you change the text depending on what is already displayed.

```
function toggleChevron(e) {
    var text = $(e.target).html();

  if( $(e.target).find('i').hasClass('fa-angle-down') ) {
    $(e.target).html( text.replace('ADVANCED', 'BASIC') );
  } else {
    $(e.target).html( text.replace('BASIC', 'ADVANCED') );
  }

  $(e.target)
    .find('i')
    .toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down');
}

$('#accordion').on('click', toggleChevron);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L03e5hty/2/

**EDIT :** better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936572/4861854)